# I want to write the ouput of displayDirectoryContents to a excel sheet

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to write the output of the displayDirectoryContents to a excel sheet

I have tried using the Apache POI method I want to get the output to a excel sheet 
Folder and filename in one column and 
the name of the files in another column
import statements

```
public class Excel {

private static String dest = "C:\\Users\\mahselva\\testexcel.xls";
private static HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
private static HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet();

public static void excelLog(String filename, String message, int rowNum) 
{

HSSFRow myRow = null;
HSSFCell myCell = null;
String excelData[][] = new String[1][2];
excelData[0][0] = filename;
excelData[0][1] = message;

myRow = mySheet.createRow(rowNum);

for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum < 2; cellNum++) {
    myCell = myRow.createCell(cellNum);
    myCell.setCellValue(excelData[0][cellNum]);

}
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    myWorkBook.write(out);
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
File currentDir = new File("C:\\OracleATS\\openScript"); // current 
directory
displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
}
public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
try {
    int i = 0;
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            Path path = Paths.get(file.getCanonicalPath());
            //System.out.println("Folder" 
+path.getFileName().toString());
            excelLog("Folder",path.getFileName().toString(),i);
            i++;
            displayDirectoryContents(file);
        } else {
            Path path = Paths.get(file.getCanonicalPath());
            //System.out.println(path.getFileName().toString());
            excelLog("File",path.getFileName().toString(),i);
            i++;
        }

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
}
}
```

I want two columns in an excel sheet with column 1 containing  File or 
Folder and column 2 containing the name of the file/folder
eg
File   books.xml
Folder Script

Thus i want to write the output to the excel sheet
i am using the function excel log to write to the output screen

Comment: I am not sure what's the question, I guess its "how to write my output in an excel file" .

Comment: I want to write the output to an excel file so that folders are present in column 1 and files in column 2 of the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

I use this to write to an excel - however I make it .csv format, not xls. Therefore this might not be what you need, but it's still partially useful as it's writing in a file that can be opened by excel efortlessly.

```
public static void printAtFile(String filename, String header, String content[])
    {
        filename+=".csv";
        System.out.println("Start creating file "+filename);
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(filename);
            writer.println(header);
            for(String u:content)
                writer.println(u);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error while writing at file "+filename);
        }
    }
```